# Is Docker BuildKit considered stable / production-friendly?

Tags: docker

Is using `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build ...` considered stable (i.e. production-ready) or experimental/beta if I'm not using `# syntax = docker/dockerfile:experimental` in my Dockerfile?

I know the buildkit frontend is still experimental... obviously, or they'd use a different tag.

Several search queries didn't turn up anyone saying "don't use this in production," but that's still very different from "Yeah, it's unlikely you'll run into issues."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Buildkit itself is distributed with the current stable releases of docker and available behind a feature flag (not an experimental flag). The only reason I'm aware of for it not to be the default is Windows native image building still needs work. For anyone building Linux images, I'd consider it stable, and know various customers that already do.

"Production-ready" usually isn't the right term for the build system. The build runs at the beginning of development, and if there are issues with the resulting image, you should know long before it reaches production.

What you'll see different is faster builds, cache stored in a different location (no longer visible as dangling images), a different UI in the build output, and lots of new features that aren't available in the classic build command (so be careful using those if you want your Dockerfile to be backwards compatible).

Answer (score 0):

AS stated in the [project page](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/tree/v0.7.1): "As the experimental syntaxes may change in future revisions, you may want to pin the image to a specific revision"

I usually go for the second or third latest version when I don't want to change my code every time a new bug is found.

Latest version at the moment would be :

```
docker/dockerfile:1.1.7-experimental
```